# How to make form buttons equal in size in Bootstrap3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to make visible buttons equal in width without hardcoding fixed width to each of them? Is there universal solution that will work with any size of button (as this is text dependent)

Here is the snipped:

```
<div class="btn-toolbar">
<button class="btn-success btn btn-default" name="resolution" value="corrected" type="submit">Submit</button>
<div class="pull-right btn-group">
<button class="btn-warning btn btn-default" name="resolution" value="skipped" type="submit">Skip</button>
<button class="btn-warning btn btn-default" name="resolution" value="not_found" type="submit">Not found</button>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: put same width on your buttons

Comment: just add a css rule on your buttons so they would have an equal sizes

Comment: How to do it without setting fixed size to each button? (doesnt matter if via width attrubute or style)

Comment: You can use width 100% for button and wrap it inside bootstrap's classes. e.g --Use <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6"> <buttons value="submit"> Submit </buttons> </div> <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6"> <buttons value="Skip " > Skip </buttons> </div>

Answer (score 0):

It will not be a good thing to make all the buttons with a fixed width, because the buttons width will rely on the text of the button. It will not look good. But if it is a must for you then you can add a class to your button and assign a fixed width to that class on your css rule. Or you cal also directly set a fixed width to your **button** on your css. But I highly recommend not to do that as it is not going to look good. Adding code for both the scenarios

By Adding a class

```
<button class="btn-warning btn btn-default fixed_width" name="resolution" value="skipped" type="submit">Skip</button>
```

On your CSS file

```
.fixed_width{
    width:**YOUR_DESIRED_WIDTH_GOES_HERE**;
}
```

Or by directly assigning -

```
button{
    width:**YOUR_DESIRED_WIDTH_GOES_HERE**;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this only by setting the required width of the button in the style. Here in the example I have given the required width to 100px. You can put this to your required value.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <style>
        .btn{
          width: 100px;
        }
      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="btn-toolbar">
        <button class="btn-success btn btn-default" name="resolution" value="corrected" type="submit">Submit</button>
        <div class="pull-right btn-group">
            <button class="btn-warning btn btn-default" name="resolution" value="skipped" type="submit">Skip</button>
            <button class="btn-warning btn btn-default" name="resolution" value="not_found" type="submit">Not found</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```